# Is there a way for me to loop an append function with different elements?

Tags: python

I'm not sure if I am wording this right because I'm not that familiar with coding terms.
Is there a way for me to loop an append function with different elements in a list?
basically, I want to loop this code without removing the return statement.

```
def create_party(party,candidates):      
    suggested_parties = party             
    suggested_parties.append(candidates[0])
    print(suggested_parties)          
    suggested_parties.pop()                
    suggested_parties.append(candidates[1]) 
    print(suggested_parties)                
    suggested_parties.pop()                 
    suggested_parties.append(candidates[2]) 
    return suggested_parties
```

The output should look like this:

```
[a,b,c,d,e,f]
[a,b,c,d,e,g]
[a,b,c,d,e,h]
```

assuming that

```
party = [a,b,c,d,e] 
candidates[0] is f
candidates[1] is g
candidates[2] is h
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a for loop like so:

```
def create_party(party,candidates):
   for item in candidates:
      print(party + list(item))
```

This prints the original list together with the next item in candidates, as one list.

So the following:

```
party = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
candidates = ["1", "2", "3"]


def create_party(party, candidates):
    for item in candidates:
        print(party + list(item))


create_party(party, candidates)
```

prints:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', '1']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', '2']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', '3']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop.

```
def create_party(party,candidates):
    for candidate in candidates[:-1]:
        party.append(candidate)
        print(party)
        party.pop()
    party.append(candidates[-1])
    return party
```

There's no need to create a new variable `suggested_parties`, you can use the same `party` variable.

Since you don't want to print the list that gets returned, the loop iterates over a slice of the `candidates` list that doesn't include the last element. Then it appends the last element and returns that.

Comment: using append and pop is absolutely redundant

Comment: wouldn't this create 4 lists, with 3 and 4 being the same list, since you are returning the party? I was wondering if I could only print 3 lists without removing the return statement.

Comment: @snatchysquid I know, I was just showing the OP how to do the same thing as the code in the question, but using a loop.

Comment: @Moyk This doesn't create any lists. `append()` and `pop()` simply modify the existing list.

Comment: @Barmar 
I meant with the return statement,
the output would look like 
[a,b,c,d,e,f]
[a,b,c,d,e,g]
[a,b,c,d,e,h] 
[a,b,c,d,e,h] 
The reason why I asked this problem is because I wanted to find a way to loop the code without removing the return statement.
That is why in my original code (the one on the post), there are 2 print and 1 return to get an output that looks like this:
[a,b,c,d,e,f]
[a,b,c,d,e,g]
[a,b,c,d,e,h] 
I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Now it loops over all elements except the last one. It's not clear what the point of this function is. Why is it printing all those other lists?

Comment: And you would only get a duplicate list in the output if the caller also prints the returned list. If the function does all the printing, why would the caller also need to print?